# gameObject.SetActive(true) wont activate my gameObject, it remains disabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: this is my little code in my script]

[image: This is my Sceneview with the gameObject]

I tried several things to get my gameObject to Activate, but it just wont't... Can somebody help?

Comment: A gameObject cannot set itself "active" if it is not active.  See docs: `Start is called on the frame *when a script is enabled* just before any of the Update methods are called the first time.`

Comment: In general don't post images of code ... also note though that from you screenshot the file haven't been saved so Unity was probably still using an older "version" of it that might not have this line added yet ... (green a lines changed and saved, yellow are lines that haven't been saved .. and the `*` next to the filename indicates there are unsaved changes -> Unity didn't recompile and use those)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Canvas to the gameObject and now its working... wow